# Profiling in debug mode

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, profiling, qt-creator

I often read that you should profile in release mode, such that the compiler performs optimisations. If I however profile in debug mode in qt creator it is easier to see which function eats performance, since no functions are inlined. It's just clearer what part of the code causes performance problems.

I therefore sometimes profile in debug and release mode. If I'm interested in a particular part of my code, the information I get in debug mode is just clearer. It helps finding problem with computational complexity.

Are there recommendations regarding profiling in aspect of what I wrote above? Are there "best practices" regarding profiling in general?

Comment: You shouldn't profile in debug mode because the function-calls which take a lot of performance in debug mode might be heavily inlined and optimized in release mode. An example: I have some code which preprocesses some data for another part of my program, in debug mode it takes very well over 5 seconds, in release mode it's done in 0.1 seconds. Thats why debug-mode profiling is bad.

Comment: You can't make code running in`O(n*n)` into something running logarithmic time by simply making a release version.  If your code is slow due to computational complexity, you will see it manifest itself in both release and debug versions.

Comment: @Paul, but I see that much better in Debug mode since no inlining is performed. Especially if I have several functions that are all inlined but called from the same function: in release mode I would not know which one causes the problem.

Comment: The problem is that often the functions eat performance **because** they are not inlined. This is also similar to asking Usain Bolt to walk slowly, so you can clock him easier.

Comment: Also it's not just about inlining. If a function in debug takes 10seconds to complete but in release it's optimized away with a NOP, do you still really want to optimize it yourself?

Comment: @dani: [*Here is why I would say you are right*](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/329124/2429), in spite of the common wisdom that says otherwise.